# How do you ensure the area of a reactive probability density function is fixed to 1?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following code which allows the user to adjust the parameters of the *beta* distribution (p, q) via the Shiny GUI.

However, as theta must be within the range 0 to 1, my code is missing a step that basically ensures the area under the curve is always equal to 1 regardless of parameter choice.

I cannot think how to go about this so any help is much appreciated.

```
# Required packages
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

# Beta plot function
betaFun <- function(p = 1.1, q = 1.1){

  prior <- function(theta){
    (theta ^ (p - 1)) * ((1 - theta) ^ (q - 1))
  }

  priorFill <- function(theta){
    ifelse(prior(theta) > 0 & prior(theta) < 1, prior(theta), NA)
  }

  ggplot(data = data.frame(x = as.double(0)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = prior, col = 'blue') +
  stat_function(fun = priorFill, geom = "area", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 0, color = 'blue') +
  xlim(0, 1) +
  ylim(0, 1)

}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Beta Distribution"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("pInput", "Parameter p", min = 1.1, max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.1),
      sliderInput("qInput", "Parameter q", min = 1.1, max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.1)
  ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("betaPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$betaPlot <- renderPlot({
    betaFun(p = input$pInput,
            q = input$qInput)
  })
}

# Execution
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Get the constants here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to calculate all the values before running ggplot (instead of on the fly using `stat_function`) so that you can normalize to an area of one up front. Then you can plot using `geom_line` instead of `stat_function`. For example:

```
# Required packages
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

# Beta plot function
betaFun <- function(p = 1.1, q = 1.1){

  theta = seq(0,1,length=1000)
  dat = data.frame(theta, prior=(theta ^ (p - 1)) * ((1 - theta) ^ (q - 1)))
  dat$prior = dat$prior/(sum(dat$prior)*mean(diff(theta)))  # Normalize to area = 1

  ggplot(dat, aes(theta, prior)) +
    geom_line(color="blue") +
    geom_area(alpha=0.2, fill="blue") +
    geom_segment(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 0, color = 'blue') +
    xlim(0, 1) +
    ylim(0, 5) +
    theme_classic(base_size=15)

}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Beta Distribution"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("pInput", "Parameter p", min = 1.1, max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.1),
      sliderInput("qInput", "Parameter q", min = 1.1, max = 5, value = 1, step = 0.1)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("betaPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$betaPlot <- renderPlot({
    betaFun(p = input$pInput,
            q = input$qInput)
  })
}

# Execution
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really nice answer and just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @ Hong Ooi Indeed, however the beta function was just chosen for the MWE.